# Big .CSV file reading issue in C#

Tags: c#

I am try to read .csv file using **oledb connection** and **File.ReadAllLine("test.csv")** but its give exception "Out of Memory exception" in this both way.

My file approx 1,80,00,000 Recores in file. file size max 2GB or more.

Please Help me....

Comment: Can you read the file *line by line*? `File.ReadLines("test.scv")`

Comment: Maybe you should parse it line-by-line, instead of trying to read everything into memory at once?

Comment: What *actually* would you like to do with the file? Often *Linq* (instead of *oledb*) is a better option.

Comment: What's the size of RAM? and Are you running your application in 64 bit mode or Any Cpu? Probably this is because you compiled your application  for 32 bit architecture.

Comment: Are  you on 32 bit and what's your ram! I might be worried if your RAM can handle such large volume of data

Comment: i am using 32 bit. and i tested my file using File.ReadLines("test.scv") but is also give "Out of Memory exception".  i tested on my local machine 4GB RAM and my test server 16GB and live server 48GB RAM but its also give error....

Comment: As Dmitry said, what do you want to do with the data once you have read it in? If you are importing it into a database there are better ways to handle large data sets. Add some more information to your question, such as what you are trying to do & the database server you are using. And NEVER TEST ON LIVE SERVERS!